# Is data width of an external DDR memory the same as the pins used to transfer data?

Tags: datasheet, memory, ddr

I'm trying to configure a Memory Interface Generator IP in Vivado. Somehow, the Block Automation doesn't work and I've to do it myself.

The board I'm using is the [Arty A7](https://digilent.com/shop/arty-a7-artix-7-fpga-development-board/) development board. It [has](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/arty-a7/reference-manual) a DDR3L SDRAM on it. The [reference manual](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/arty-a7/reference-manual) of the board states that the data width of the external memory is 16-bit. I also checked the schematic and saw that there are 16 pins for data transfers. See below.

[image: Schematic Screenshot]

Does the data width of an external memory is the same as the pins/lines used for the connection? What is the limit for it? From which part of the [memory part datasheet](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/2gb_1_35v_ddr3l.pdf?rev=4f46f8613ff2467c9f3428e9043d0098) can I determine this data width thing?

Answer (score 2):

It reads in the documentation that the chip has a 16-bit wide bus and also if there are multiple chips they are still connected to same 16-bit wide bus, instead of making a wider 32-bit bus.

So yes, the data bus is 16-bit, and there are 16-bit chips there.

Comment: On which page is it written?

Comment: The DDR3 section of the Arty reference manual.